# Boolean Compliment Simplification

Tags: math, boolean

If I have a simplified Boolean expression:
F(X, Y, Z) = Y'Z + X'YZ' + XY'

and gets its compliment:
F’(X, Y, Z) = (Y + Z')(X+Y'+Z)(X'+Y)

Would the compliment also be simplified, or would I need to simplify it?

Comment: You can simplify it to `XY + X'Y'Z' + YZ`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg So the comoliment wont be simlified?

Comment: The formula I provided is the simplification of the compliment.